# Getting all undeclared variables from query

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, sql-server-2019

Imagine you try to run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers c
WHERE id = @id
    AND dateTimeCreated = @date
```

You'll get an error message along the lines of `Must declare the scalar variable "@id".`

As I understand it, this happens during the initial parsing of the query, before any code is executed.

Is it possible to get SQL Server to report *all* the missing variables at once, or is this just how the query parser works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Error list**

The error list might give you what you need:

You could open `View --> Error List` in ssms

[image]

To get all the build + intelliSense errors:

[image]

---

Differences between error list & the messages tab on query execution:

**Error list**

> The Error List contains all syntax and semantic errors found by
>   IntelliSense in the Database Engine Editor. This list of errors is
>   dynamically updated as you edit Transact-SQL scripts. The list
>   includes all errors that the editor has found in each Transact-SQL
>   script. The editor does not stop parsing a file after encountering
>   errors in a script. In SQL Server 2008, IntelliSense in the Database
>   Engine Editor does not support all Transact-SQL syntax elements. The
>   Error List contains only errors from the Transact-SQL syntax that is
>   supported by IntelliSense.

**Messages Tab**

> The Messages tab at the bottom of the Database Engine Query Editor
>   window displays all errors and messages that are returned by the SQL
>   Server Database Engine when a Transact-SQL script is executed. This
>   list does not change until you execute the script again. The Database
>   Engine stops parsing a batch after it finds one or two compile errors;
>   therefore, the Messages tab might not list all errors in a script.
>   [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/transact-sql-debugger-error-list-window?view=sql-server-ver15#transact-sql-errors-in-management-studio)

So to answer the question:

> Is it possible to get SQL Server to report all the missing variables
>   at once, or is this just how the query parser works?

Using general query excecution this is not possible as the parsing stops after one or two compile errors, but you could use the error list.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm actually calling this query from inside .NET I was hoping it'd be possible to get the errors results from the query execution, but your answer makes it clear that's not possible without some kind of a SQL parsing library like the one built into SSMS.

Comment: @PetterBrodin Happy to help :). There could definitely be better solutions than the one shown here, hopefully a new answer is added with a better solution.